# Contingency table when you have a column with count values

Tags: r, tidyverse, contingency

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Year      Var    Count
2019       A     10
2020       B     23
2019       B     36
2020       A     42
```

How can I make a Year x Var contingency table using the "Count" column as frequencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `xtabs` in `base R`

```
xtabs(Count ~ Year + Var, df1)
#        Var
#Year    A  B
#   2019 10 36
#   2020 42 23
```

To include the row/column totals, can use `addmargins`

```
addmargins(xtabs(Count ~ Year + Var, df1))
#     Var
#Year     A   B Sum
#  2019  10  36  46
#  2020  42  23  65
#  Sum   52  59 111
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L), Var = c("A", 
"B", "B", "A"), Count = c(10L, 23L, 36L, 42L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a way I can include the column totals and row totals as well?

Answer (score 4):

In `tidyverse` with the help of  `janitor` you can do :

```
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var, values_from = Count) %>%
  adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col"))

#  Year  A  B Total
#  2019 10 36    46
#  2020 42 23    65
# Total 52 59   111
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `reshape` to make it "wide", i.e.,

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Year",
  timevar = "Var"
)
```

gives

```
  Year Count.A Count.B
1 2019      10      36
2 2020      42      23
```